# Javascript - How to insert a variable value into a database from MQTT

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, mqtt

I've written a program that listens to a public MQTT channel and prints any incoming messages ---> this works well

I have a bit of code in the same program that can read and write from a local database I have ---> this works well

I want to insert the message that is printed from the MQTT channel INTO a table in my database.

I've looked around for solutions and tried all sorts, but I can't seem to get anywhere with the solutions and help in the other topics.

Edit: My table is called 'sensors' and it has 1 column called 'value'

**EDIT2:**

My function:

```
if (data) {
       //do database update or print
       console.log("----");
       console.log("temp: %s", data);
       connection.query('INSERT INTO sensors  VALUES ??', [data],  function (error, results, fields) {
        // When done with the connection, release it.
        //connection.release();
        console.log(results);
        // Handle error after the release.
        if (error) throw error;
      });
       //reset to undefined for next time
       data = undefined;
    }
```

Currently fails to write to my table. but it can listen and read fine
Any suggestions?

Comment: Why can't you execute the connection.query logic inside your mqtt callback method? You can use the message variable instead of "test" data right ? Your answer is already there in your question

Comment: @SantoshBalaji Hi, I thought of this exactly when i got into bed, I'm testing it now! Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue. It turned out to be a syntax error

here's the solution

```
if (data) {
   //do database update or print
   console.log("----");
   console.log("temp: %s", data);
   connection.query('INSERT INTO sensors VALUE (?)', data,  function (error, results, fields) {
    // When done with the connection, release it.
    //connection.release();
    console.log(results);
    // Handle error after the release.
    if (error) throw error;
  });
   //reset to undefined for next time
   data = undefined;
}

  });
```